# Can my video card support two DVI monitors?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, vga, dvi

My HP Phenom II PC support two monitors with the video card in it.  I've checked the driver and it's an ATI Radeon HD 4650. I've looked it up on [AMD's website](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-4000/hd-4600/Pages/hd-4600-specs.aspx) and it looks like the driver is capable of it, but looking at the video card on my PC it has only three out ports: DVI, VGA and HDMI.

Does that mean it can support something like one DVI monitor and one VGA monitor (or some other combination of the three), or can I get an adapter for the DVI port to split the output between two DVI monitors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most modern cards (your included) are powerful enough to drive at least two heads (monitors). In your case you have two digital outputs (HDMI and DVI) and one analog (VGA). You should be able to power your two monitors using any combination of these ports however you best bet for quality would be to get a monitor that supports HDMI input or a converter that takes the HDMI out on the card and changes it to DVI.

HDMI -> DVI converters (cables and adapters) are readily available at most major electronics suppliers.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can connect your second monitor to the HDMI output using an HDMI cable. If your second monitor has no HDMI input, you can use an HDMI-to-DVI [adapter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/797582-REG/Iogear_GHDFDVIMW6_HDMI_to_DVI_Adapter.html) or adapter cable:

[image: HDMI-to-DVI adapter]